# Comparing a text field with a Database Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net

Fairly new to C# and ASP.net so some help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm in the process of trying to compare the Readings from a Photocopier. The business rule is that the Reading must be higher than the previous year.

This is in my controller:

```
var checkMeterReading = (from p in db.MeterReading
                                     where (p.Reading == meterReading.Reading)
                                     select p);

if (checkMeterReading.Count() > 0)
{
 Allows it to be saved
}
```

I just want to know if I'm going about it the right way or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `meterReading` here?

Comment: meterReading is an instance of my MeterReading class that I have as a parameter in my create method

Answer (score 3):

> The business rule is that the Reading must be higher than the previous
>   year.

if this the case and per your comment if `meterReading` instance holds the previous year values then your posted condition is wrong, You should check for `>` and not equality `==`

```
where (p.Reading > meterReading.Reading)
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work, it still allows me to progress to enter in the reading

Answer (score 0):

I had my logic wrong way around. It needed to be:

```
where (p.Reading < meterReading.Reading)
```

instead of:

```
   where (p.Reading > meterReading.Reading)
```